# Does setting an item in a WeakMap modify the key itself?

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, does setting an item in a [WeakMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap) alter the object used as the key?

The reason I ask is that, if I were to implement a WeakMap, then I might stick a Symbol on the key, and then use this to key into the value. In this way no memory reference would be maintained from the WeakMap to the value.

...and I can't think of any other way of doing it.

The following works, indicating that if the key is modified, it is not modified in a normal userland fashion?

```js
const o= Object.freeze({})
const m = new WeakMap

m.set(o, 'this is o')

console.log(m.has(o)) // true
```

Comment: I don't think so. Can you show an example of where you think it does?

Comment: According to the ECMAScript section about weakmap `set` (https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-weakmap.prototype.set) it **shouldn't**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The [Specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-weakmap.prototype.set) does not define that some property gets set on the key, thus an implementation may not do so.

It might use some internal mechanisms though to link the key back to the Weakmap, however that has to be invisible to an observer.

> WeakMap and WeakSets are intended to provide mechanisms for dynamically associating state with an object in a manner that does not “leak” memory resources if, in the absence of the WeakMap or WeakSet, the object otherwise became inaccessible and subject to resource reclamation by the implementation's garbage collection mechanisms. *This characteristic can be achieved by using an inverted per-object mapping of weak map instances to keys.*
>
> ~ [Weakmap, ES262](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-weakmap-objects)

Comment: (side note), the "implementation steps" about the `set` method does **not** seem to mention any key alteration whatsoever: https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-weakmap.prototype.set